# ExtendedExecutionSession in Windows 10 UAP

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have troubles using ExtendedExecutionSession in Windows 10 UAP.

First, it seems that ExtendedExecutionSession.RequestExtensionAsync only returns Allowed if it is called from the app Suspending event handler. If it is called outside this event handler the method returns Denied.

Second, most critical problem. My app executes downloads. If any download is in progress I request ExtendedExecutionSession to allow downloads to complete. What I found at least on Windows 10 mobile though is ExtendedExecutionSession is allowed in app on suspend but downloads seem to freeze. Nothing is downloaded while app is in background and when app is resumed downloads appear frozen with no data transferred.

Comment: why not just use the background downloader?

Comment: I can't use it. I need more control over downloads that background downloader provides..

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MSDN guidance for Extended Execution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-minimized-with-extended-execution

SavingData is the only type of Extended Execution Reason that can be used in the Suspending state. Note that this is specifically for saving critical user data locally that will be lost once the process is removed from memory.

It sounds like you should use the Unspecified Extended Execution if you need to accomplish something when your app is running and in the foreground. It will be revoked if the user decides to close the app before the download operation completes. Like was previously suggested, a background transfer or use of the ApplicationTrigger or MaintenanceTrigger may be better options for these downloads if you want them to continue after your app has been closed.